# spark - how to import external packages

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am dealing with a strange issue when using spark-shell with an external package that allow us to connect using MS eventhubs.

First I start Spark shell with the command

```
spark-shell --packages com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.1.0 --master local[*]
```

when declaring a structured streaming query

```
val inputStream = sparkSession.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(eventhubParameters).load()
```

I get this error

> scala> val inputStream = sparkSession.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(eventhubParameters).load()
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: eventhubs. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:594)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:197)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:125)
>     ... 50 elided
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eventhubs.DefaultSource
>     at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(DataSource.scala:579)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(DataSource.scala:579)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25.apply(DataSource.scala:579)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25.apply(DataSource.scala:579)
>     at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:579)
>     ... 57 more

As another tentative, creating a scala standalone application using Scala IDE, referencing all spark libraries and azure eventhub streaming jar, everything works correctly.
Any suggestion for the problem when using spark-shell?

Thanks
Roberto

Comment: Can you change the `--packages` to use `spark-streaming-eventhubs_connector_2.11` instead? See https://github.com/hdinsight/spark-eventhubs/blob/master/pom.xml#L24

Comment: Hi Jacek, same issue when using spark streaming.eventhubs_connector_2.11

Comment: What version of spark are you using? `streaming.eventhubs_connector_2.11` is for spark version 2.x while `streaming.eventhubs_connector_2.10` is for 1.6.